Convert hexadecimal StringArray to FixedSizeBinaryArray
I have an array of ethereum addresses in hexadecimal format (20 bytes), encoded as an hexadecimal string. How can I transform that into a FixedSizeBinaryArray?
I tried using cast:
>>> import pyarrow as pa
>>> a = pa.array([
    '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000042', 
    '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000006e', 
    '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000037',
])
>>> a.cast(pa.binary())
<pyarrow.lib.BinaryArray object at 0x7f937829e200>
[
  307830303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303432,
  307830303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303665,
  307830303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303337
]

But, as expected, the results are not what I want. In my case the new array should have 66, then 110, then 55.
I can't convert to int and then to bytes because it doesn't fit in 64bits (nor decimal's 128 bits).

You need to drop the leading 0x from your hex string, convert them to binary and put then in an array.
import pyarrow as pa

addresses = pa.array([
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000042",
    "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000006e",
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000037",
])

binary_array = pa.array((bytes.fromhex(x.as_py()[2:]) for x in addresses), pa.binary(20))

assert isinstance(binary_array, pa.FixedSizeBinaryArray)

assert binary_array.to_pylist() == [
    b"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B",
    b"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00n",
    b"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x007",
]



Each item represents a different address. I edited the question to make it clearer. And how can I apply it to every row?

See the updated answer.

I was aiming for a more "arrownic" way of doing it, but it seems that, even though it has some compute functions, the aim of the library is data manipulation and not data science.
I tried with .to_numpy() and then converting back and its faster than @0x26res 's answer
In [1] %timeit pa.array((bytes.fromhex(x.as_py()[2:]) for x in table['minerAddress']), pa.binary(20))
142 ms ± 2.46 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [2] to_eth = np.vectorize(lambda x: bytes.fromhex(x[2:]))
In [3] %timeit pa.array(to_eth(table['minerAddress'].to_numpy()), pa.binary(20))
66.1 ms ± 341 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

